# Set pandas dataframe equal to values not in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to divide into a test and training dataframe for a data analytics exercise.
I have an accidents database which has 3 grades of accident - 1,2,3.
I want to write an equal sample size of each to a training dataframe, and then write the ones which were not added here to the test dataframe. The training dataframe is working fine, but the test dataframe is not.

My code is as below.

```
def split_df(dataframe, train_df, test_df, val_low, val_high, sample_size): 
    for i in range (val_low, val_high): 
        if(i == val_low): 
            dataframe = accidents.loc[accidents['Accident_Severity'] == i].sample(n = sample_size)
            train_df = accidents.loc[accidents['Accident_Severity'] == i].sample(n = math.trunc(sample_size*0.7))
        else: 
            dataframe = dataframe.append(accidents.loc[accidents['Accident_Severity'] == i].sample(n = sample_size))
            train_df = train_df.append(accidents.loc[accidents['Accident_Severity'] == i].sample(n = math.trunc(sample_size*0.7)))
        
    test_df = accidents[~train_df] #(This is the problem - how do I write the values not in the train_df dataframe to the test_df?) 
    
    return dataframe, train_df, test_df
```

So the test_df is everything which is not in the train_df.

Answer (score 1):

As you already found elements, which you will keep. I start after that point. In a pandas dataframe each element has an unique index.
Using the method `index` of an pandas dataframe, you get a list of indexes which are present in the training set. The following line of code looks for index which are in accicdents (the full dataframe), but are missing in the train_df.

```
index = accidents.index.difference(train_df.index)
```

Next step would be to select these indexes from the accidents dataframe.

Caution: There is a method to reindex a dataframe. If you use this before comparing indexes. Don't wonder why it is not working. The indexes are no independent between the two dataframes.